# Google Apps Script Doesn't Work When Embedded. TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, embed, google-sites

The Google Apps Script runs perfectly from the Web App URL but when I embed it into a Google Site via Insert > Apps Script then I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of null.`

This is the code:

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();`

I tried enabling the Advanced Google Services Google Sheets API and Google Drive API. It still won't work. Somehow it loses connection to the sheet once embedded. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()` because you're not running the script from a spreadsheet, you're running it from a site so you don't actually have any spreadsheet/sheet 'active' as such.

Use `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("").getSheetByName("")` instead.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the suggested edit, easy mistake to make! Please mark the answer as correct if this solved your issue!